# Workbox service worker issue

Tags: laravel, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

i have the following workbox.config.js file configuration for pwa project

```
module.exports = {
"globDirectory": "public/",
"globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{png,xml,css,ico,jpg,svg,js}"
],
"swDest": "public/service-worker.js",
"swSrc": "resources/js/service-worker.js",
"globIgnores": [
    'notusing/**/*',
    'js/service-worker.js',
    'service-worker.js',
    'zsw.js'
  ]
};
```

and i have below the project file structure

```
public
|   +-- css
|       +--style.css
|   +-- js
|       +-- jquery.js
|   +-- html
|       +-- sample.html
```

when i execute from terminal like `npm run build` it generates new serviceworker.js file but it wont include .html files from html folder in public. can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The `globPatterns` config controls the set of files that are picked up and included in your precache manifest. Your current config does not include the `html` extension, so it doesn't pick up any HTML files.

Something like this should help:

```
module.exports = {
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{html,png,xml,css,ico,jpg,svg,js}"
  ],
  //...other options here...
};
```